# Updating a text from a plist to every touch of the screen

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, plist

I'm searching for some phrases from a plist, and would like to update such statements to the screen every touch, but I can not find a solution to the problem, so I ask help on how to implement this, my code is below.

```
int RecordIndexDitados = 0;

NSMutableArray *dictDitados;

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Ditados.plist"];
NSDictionary *plistData = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];

NSDictionary *ditados = [plistData objectForKey:@"Ditados"];
NSMutableArray *selection = [[ditados objectForKey:@"Selection"] mutableCopy];

RecordIndexDitados = arc4random()%[selection count];

// Select and display currently selected record from the array.
dictDitados = [selection objectAtIndex:RecordIndexDitados]

CCLabel *ditados = [CCLabel labelWithString:@"Question" 
                                     dimensions:CGSizeMake(400, 200)
                                      alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter
                                       fontName:@"Brush Script" fontSize:36];
    ditados.color = ccc3(0, 74, 128);
    [ditados setPosition:ccp(240, 120)];
    [self addChild: ditados];
    [ditados setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dictDitados]];

<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Ditados</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Selection</key>
        <array>
            <string>Text 1</string>
            <string>Text 2</string>
            <string>Text 3</string>     
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: please supply an example of your plist

Answer (score 0):

why don't you load your plist in memory and update your content from there? this way you load your data from the plist only once..not every time you touch the screen.

Answer (score 0):

1st read the contents of plist into some temp object(string,array or directory) as you designed plist.

2nd know insert the updated value into temp object.

3rd assign the temp object to main object.

4th write the main object into file.

For your better understanding refer this like:

http://iphonesdevsdk.blogspot.com/2011/04/plist.html

it may helps you.